# How can I include a custom titlepage in my document?

Tags: titles

How can I do title page like [image: this](http://min.us/mchibO5)]?

I'm using the  `mwrep` document class.

Or could it be simpler, and it is possible to include a `pdf` with this title page to `pdf` generated by LEd?

How can I disable page number on title page?

How can I make title page not count into numbering (next page would have number 1)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to prepare the title page as a separate PDF file, say with Scribus or LibreOffice or whatever. Then you can simply say

```
\usepackage{pdfpages} % <-- this goes in the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf{title}
\end{titlepage}
...
```

if `title.pdf` is the file you prepared. If you load the **emptypage** package, the blank pages won't have anything on them.

Comment: OK, that works, except my pdf file has two pages and your code onsly includes first page from them.

Comment: (Since I only added the first page of your document as in image, egreg couldn't have known that.) If you check the documentation for `pdfpages` you can find that adding `[pages=1-]` to the `\includepdf` command will do what you want.